# Understanding the regex [\s\S-[<>]]*

Tags: regex

I have this regex: `[\s\S-[<>]]*`

Could you please help me understand what does this expression stand for? From what I see it means a character class formed of spaces and a range from non-space characters to < or >?

It doesn't make much sense..

Thanks!

Comment: it's for Java, it applies in a XSD validator pattern: <xsd:pattern value="[\s\S-[&#x3C;&#x3E;]]*" />

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a variant only supported by a few regex engines (.NET, JGSoft, XML Schema and XPath but not for example native Java regex), and it's called [character class substraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xmlcharclass.html).

For example,

```
[A-Z-[EFG]]
```

matches any letter from `A` to `Z` except `E`, `F` or `G`.

But in your case, it really doesn't make much sense because `[\s\S]` matches any character -
the same result (in any regex flavor) can be achieved by

```
[^<>]*
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I would write [A\S-[<>]] - would this mean: "the character A or any non space character without <>"?

Comment: Or even simpler, would [\S-[<>]] mean all non space characters without <>?

Comment: @leadgy: Yes, but you can always write it differently, for example `[^\s<>]`.

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Character Classes".